# Question about divergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Is it true that if $(a_n) \geq 0$ and $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n$ diverges, then $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n(1-r^n)$ diverges for all $r \in (0,1)$? I think it's true but I'm having a hard time proving it.

Comment: Are the $a_n$ non-negative?

Comment: Then, since $r^n \leqslant r$, you have $(1-r^n) \geqslant (1-r)$ to settle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n(1-r^n)$ converges then $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{a_n(1-r^n)}{1-r^n} \to 0$ and hence $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n r^n$ also converges.